# Finding minimum number of notes to make a amount

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to programming. The problem is to find minimum number of notes that combines to *N*. All possible notes can be 1,2,5,10,50 and 100.

> My approach

I have created an array with possible notes. First considering the largest notes to minimize the number of notes, and then the 2nd largest stored in the 2nd position of the array. Here is my code:

```
t=int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    n=int(input())
    least_notes=0
    a=[100,50,10,5,2,1] #array of possible notes
    p=a[0]   #storing a[0]=100 in p
    i=0
    while(n>0):
        n=n-(p*n//p) #rest amount of money 
        least_notes+=n//p 
        i+=1 
        if(i<len(a)):
            p=a[i]
    print(least_notes)
```

But, the result for this sample input

```
3 
1200
500
242
```

is `0 0 0`(each in new lines). Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong here? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in the algorithm is in the order of two lines that should be the other way around:

```
least_notes+=n//p 
n=n-(p*n//p) #rest amount of money
```

since the `least_notes` count should be increased before `n` is updated recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same exercise.
Found this.

```
nNotesFinal =[]
Amount = 990
notesTypes = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100]

for i in list(reversed(notesTypes)):                   #For in reversed noteTypes
    numberOfEachNote = Amount // i                     #Multiples of NoteType
    nNotesFinal.append(numberOfEachNote)               #Add multiple to nNotesFinal
    Amount = Amount - Amount // i * i                  # substract Multiple of (NoteTypes * NoteTypes) from Amount

print(list(reversed(nNotesFinal)))                     #print reverser NoteTypes
```